# Unable to call .NET ASMX from PHP

Tags: php, asmx, soap-client

I have the following - *currently hosted* - SOAP service that was created in .NET that I'm trying to call from PHP:

```
POST /ExampleService/ExampleService.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: dev.examplesite.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://localhost:51713/ExampleService.asmx/RegisterPerson"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <UserCredentials xmlns="http://localhost:51713/ExampleService.asmx">
      <UserID>string</UserID>
      <AuthKey>string</AuthKey>
    </UserCredentials>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <RegisterPerson xmlns="http://localhost:51713/ExampleService.asmx">
      <requestItem>
        <RequestResult>string</RequestResult>
        <Firstname>string</Firstname>
        <Lastname>string</Lastname>
      </requestItem>
    </RegisterPerson>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and I'm trying to call it using the following PHP code:

```
<?php
    $ns = "http://dev.examplesite.com/ExampleService/ExampleService.asmx";  
    $wsdl_url = "http://dev.examplesite.com/ExampleService/ExampleService.asmx?wsdl";
    $client = new SOAPClient($wsdl_url);

    $header = new SoapHeader(
        $ns, 
        'UserCredentials', 
        array(
            'UserID' => "1", 
            'AuthKey' => "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX" 
        )
    );
    $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

    $params = array( 
        'Firstname'  => 'John', 
        'Lastname' => 'Doe'
    );

    $client->__soapCall('RegisterPerson',$params);
?>
```

This however results in the following error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:MustUnderstand] Missing required header 'UserCredentials'. in /home/devops1/public_html/asmxtest/register.php:43 Stack trace: #0 /home/devops1/public_html/asmxtest/register.php(43): SoapClient->__soapCall('RegisterPerso...', Array) #1 {main} thrown in /home/devops1/public_html/asmxtest/register.php on line 43`

I've tried a few other methods but all met with no success. One thing that concerns me is the fact that we are reaching across *over the wire* to this web service which is already hosted on a testing server, and the **localhost:51713** is ringing alarm bells. Should this be changed to a fully qualified domain name such as `dev.examplesite.com`?

Comment: My best guess is that manually setting the headers for username/password is not the right way, and its being overwritten.. But that's just a guess tough.. Could easily do this 1 request with curl though

Comment: Thanks for the reply hanshenrik. Kindly elaborate

Comment: possible proxy/firewall issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For as easy as the SoapClient is supposed to be, I've never had success w/ it.  In just about every case we have rolled our own process, which always seemed to work better.

Example:

```
// set our headers to pass in cURL
$headers = array(
    'Content-type: text/xml;charset="utf-8"',
    'Accept: text/xml',
    'Cache-Control: no-cache',
    'Pragma: no-cache',
    'SOAPAction: ' . $action,
    'Content-length: '.strlen($soap)
 );

 // initiate cURL
 try {
    $_ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($_ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($_ch, CURLOPT_URL, WEB_SERVICE_URL);
    curl_setopt($_ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($_ch, USERPWD, USER_ID . ":" . PASSWORD);
    curl_setopt($_ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($_ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($_ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($_ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $soap);
    curl_setopt($_ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    // process the request and get the result back
    $response = curl_exec($_ch);
    curl_close($_ch);
    return $response;
 } catch (Exception $e) {
    capDebug(__FILE__, __LINE__, "Error calling the web service: " . $e->getMessage(), "/tmp/errors.log");
    return false;
 }
```

We've had to massage the data afterwards, but it always works!